# Why is page posted when using jquery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

My code is successfully saving the data into the database. But despite using jquery ajax, when method is done it open the new page :- (http://localhost:3721/Home/Save) and displays just 'True'.

I need to stay on the same page where I called the button event from and displays the Alert message.

Here is my jquery code :-

```
$("#btnSave").on("click", function() {
    var text = $("#txtText").val();
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var url = "/Home/Save";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: "{ 'id' :'" + id + "','text' : '" + text + "'}",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result === true)
                alert("Record Saved");
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("Error...failed");
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my controller method:-

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Save(int id, string text)
{
    return(_repo.SaveRecord(id, text));
}
```

Comment: is `#btnSave` a form's submit button? If so you'll have to cancel the default action of submitting the form.

Comment: You need to share HTML.

Comment: Never use `click` for form submissions. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things wrong:

1. You have a typo: it should say type: "POST", not tyupe.
2. You should return false from the JavaScript function to avoid that behaviour.
3. Your ASP.NET MVC method should return a JsonResult so you have more control about what the AJAX server-side method return.
4. Last but not least, try to stringify the object you send from the client to avoid security issues.

Answer (score 1):

Very important: Never use `click` events with form posting. The form still submits via a keypress. Use the `submit` event instead.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // Stop form submit
    var text = $("#txtText").val();
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var url = "/Home/Save";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: "{ 'id' :'" + id + "','text' : '" + text + "'}",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result === true)
                alert("Record Saved");
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("Error...failed");
        }
    });
});
```

Also you need to prevent the default action of the submit with either `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` in the handler.

Also, as @Nick Pierpoint suggests below, you need to ensure your save button is marked as `type="submit"`. If you show your HTML it will help :)

Comment: Will need to make sure the `BUTTON` is also a `SUBMIT`.

Comment: @Nick Pierpoint: Good point. I assumed it was, but we have no HTML to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Add `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the default click event:

```
$("#btnSave").on("click", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
```